# Google Scripts: Variables Always Showing Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, google-forms

I have created a google form which works as a "Sign Up" for One of My Informative Forum.

The Data Captured in Google Forms is Assigned To A Response Spreadsheet.

The Spreadsheet is Formulated with vlookups as Per The Membership Chosen Which Works Fine.

I Want To Send Auto Emails for Anyone Signing Up Immediately After Clicking Submit, For Which I Have Created A Trigger Too.

The Problem is at The Initial Stage of Writing A Code.

**The First Code is:**

```
   function myfunction(e) {
      var recipient = e.values[1];
      var name = e.values[2];
      var membership = e.values[18]; 
      var price = e.values[19];
      var features = e.values[20];
      var paymentlink = e.values[21];
      var monthlypay = e.values[22];
      var subscriptionlink = e.values[23];
      var subject = 'Text';
      var body = 'Text'; 

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)  

}
```

This Code Worked Fine on A Test Spreadsheet, But Gives Following Error: TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code").

This Remains Unresolved.

**The Second Code is:**

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 2;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 25);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var name = row[2]; 
    var membership = row[18];
    var price = row[20]; 
    var features = row[21];
    var paymentlink = row[22];
    var message = 'Text';    
    var subject = 'Text';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

The Problem with This Code is:

1. Trigger Works Only on "Edit"
2. User Who Have Got Confirmation When The Registered First; Keeps Getting Confirmation Email Repetitively if Someone New Registers.

To Avoid The Problem of "Duplicated Emails" Mentioned in Second Code Point 2:

**I Created The Third Code Which Follows:**

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 2;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var name = row[2];
    var membership = row[18];
    var price = row[19];
    var features = row[20];
    var paymentlink = row[21];
    var monthlypay = row[22];
    var subscriptionlink = row[23];

    var emailSent = row[25];
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates

    var message = 'Text';
    var subject = 'Text';

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 25).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
}
```

The Issue with This Code is:

1. Again Trigger Works on "Edit".
2. "Email_Sent" Auto Populates for First 2 Form Entries.
3. Even After "Email_Sent" Column Gets Added: Repetitive Emails Gets Send.

**I Would Be Grateful if You Can Resolve The First Code. OR. Resolve All The Issues in Third Code.**

Thank You.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569)

Answer (score 0):

i guess ur problem is with the function argument as u know that in nodejs the function's arguments are request,response type so according to that ur first argument is the request and when u want to access it's     specific values u have to use the req.body.values and for the mail sent repeatedly u can have an additional column in ur spreadsheet having boolean flags and set and unset it according to whether the mail is sent or not and according to that u can select the recipient of ur mail.
Hope this helps